# Using an XSL cross-reference to count matching nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XSL stylsheet which select XML nodes using a key. It selects the term/info/name of desc elements with type "concept", that have an ID that corresponds to concept/@ID attribute of a desc element that is does not have an attribute type "concept". What I'm trying to do now is get a count of all the terms that have a sibling element ID that correspond to the a desc element with a specific type that isn't a concept. For example I'd like to be able to count how many terms a desc type "a" element is linked to, in this case it would be 2 terms.

**XML**

```
<rdf>
    <desc type = "a">
        <concept ID = "#1"/>
    </desc>

    <desc type = "b">
        <concept ID = "#2"/>
    </desc>

    <desc type = "concept">
        <ID>1</ID>
        <term>
            <info>
                <name>apple</name>
                <ID>1</ID>
            </info>
        </term>
        <term>
            <info>
                <name>pear</name>
                <ID>2</ID>
            </info>
        </term>
    </desc>

    <desc type = "concept">
        <ID>2</ID>
        <term>
            <info>
                <name>chocolate</name>
                <ID>1</ID>
            </info>
        </term>
    </desc>
</rdf>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:key name = "terms" match = "desc[@type = 'concept']" use = "ID"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "rdf/desc[@type != 'concept' and @type != 'a']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "desc">

        <xsl:variable name = "test" select = "key('terms', substring(concept/@ID, 2))"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$test/term/info">
            <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet currently outputs the name of the terms, which correspond to the desc element with type "b", which is "chocolate". Any help on how I can get a count of the terms as well as the name would be helpful.

Comment: I think you could just `count($test/term)`.

Comment: I have tried that but recursion doesn't seem to, it just counts 1.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Updated code and a sample of your desired output would be helpful. This is what I was thinking: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiF

Comment: Or maybe you're talking about counting each term; first term is 1, second term is 2, etc. In that case, `position()` should work. Here's an updated fiddle with both count and position: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiF/2

Comment: Nope you are right, I just put the count in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="concept" match="desc[@type = 'concept']" use="ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/rdf">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="desc[@type != 'concept']">
            <xsl:variable name="terms" select="key('concept', substring(concept/@ID, 2))/term"/>
            <desc count="{count($terms)}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$terms/info/name"/>
            </desc>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<root>
  <desc count="2">
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>pear</name>
  </desc>
  <desc count="1">
    <name>chocolate</name>
  </desc>
</root>
```